# Trying to assign an 18-input switch into six 3-bit variables

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to assign 3-bit variables equally from an 18-input switch. Here is what I have done so far:

```
module part2(U, V, W, X, Y, Z, S, SW, M);
input [2:0]U, V, W, X, Y, Z, S;
input [17:0]SW;

wire[2:0]U, V, W, X, Y, Z;
assign U = SW[2:0];
assign V = SW[5:3];
endmodule
```

However, when I try to compile I get an error:

> HDL Syntax error near text "["; expecting an operand.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not see any issue besides not declaring direction for the port M. What exactly doe it complain about? which line?

Comment: Hi @Serge, I slept on it and just opened it up again. For some reason it works now and I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem that you never declared the `M` port. You are using very old Verilog-1995 syntax for declaring ports where you have to repeat port names multiple times. Use what is called *ANSI-style* port headers and it will reduce mistakes like this.

```
module part2(
  input [2:0]U, V, W, X, Y, Z, S,
  input [17:0]SW,M);

  wire[2:0]U, V, W, X, Y, Z;
  assign U = SW[2:0];
  assign V = SW[5:3];
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the port `M` in your declaration.

You need to make it either `input/output`.

For your purpose to split the 18 bit `SW` equally among 6 3 bits nets, you can use the streaming operator as follow.

```
assign {>>{U, V, W, X, Y, Z}} = SW;
```